# For Kotlin Coroutine, where to put parentJob, when using CoroutineScope to launch?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I saw in the blog https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/coroutines-and-rxjava-an-asynchronicity-comparison-part-2-cancelling-execution-199485cdf068

```
launch(parentJob + CommonPool) {
   // my suspending block
}
```

where we could then cancel the job at the end i.e. `parentJob.cancel()`, so the job by `launch` will also be canceled.

However, if I launch it using CoroutineScope as below, where should I put my `parentJob`?

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + parentJob).launch{ 
   // ...
}
```

or

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(parentJob) {
   // ...
}
```

Or both the above is also wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**When using the first approach**

```kotlin
val parentJob = Job()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + parentJob)

scope.launch { 
    // will be cancelled
    // ...
}
scope.launch {
    // ...
    // will be cancelled
    launch {
        // will be cancelled
    }
}
scope.launch(NonCancellable) {
    // won't be cancelled now
}
parentJob.cancel()
```

All the coroutines launched using the scope will have the job attached unless some coroutine overrides it by passing the job into the coroutines like `launch` or `async`. So doing the `job.cancel()` will cancel all the coroutines running which were launched using the scope.

**When using the second approach**

```kotlin
val parentJob = Job()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
scope.launch(parentJob) {
    // will be cancelled
    launch {
        // will be cancelled
    }
}
scope.launch {
    // ...
    // this one won't be cancelled
}
parentJob.cancel()
```

The parent job is only applied to the coroutine launched using `launch`. So only that coroutine and its children will be cancelled, other coroutine in the scope won't be cancelled by cancelling the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + parentJob).launch{ 
   // ...
}
```

and since we launch the scope mostly in ViewModel if you follow the Google's Best practice, then we can basically cancel the parentJob in viewModel onClear() method